# Launching an intent to load Google Latitude from another application

Tags: android, google-maps, google-latitude

Can anyone provide me with how to launch Google Latutide (just to the main screen of it) via an intent from another application in android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, I managed to do it like this...

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.LatitudeActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an URI you can do this way:

`Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);`

`startActivity(intent);`